# Rails: Routes works locally, not on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to learn Ruby on Rails using this Rails Tutorial. Earlier, I got everything working fine but since Rails was updated to 3.2, I've tried doing it again.

I got to this point where I am trying to customize the routes for my static pages.

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout?version=3.2#sec:rails_routes

Locally, it works but when I push to Heroku, I get the default Rails page even though I have deleted public/index.html

Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do:

```
git add -u .
git commit -m "removing public/index.html file from git repo"
git push heroku master
```

that will fix it

Comment: No problem, I recommend [gitcasts.com](http://gitcasts.com/) if you're new to git :)